# Inno Setup: UnloadDLL does not work on uninstall

Tags: dll, inno-setup, uninstallation, delete-file

I'm working on an Inno Setup script and during uninstall I call a custom DLL to do some Revert operation. Unfortunately, after uninstall is completed the DLL and it's dependencies were not removed, despite the fact I called `UnloadDLL` and DeleteFile (which returns `False`).
Why does `UnloadDLL` fail?
Is there a possibility to load the DLL dynamic with `LoadLibrary`? I have seen some functions regarding this, but they are all deprecated. The DLL is built with Visual Studio with C interface.

Here's the code:

```
function Revert(param: String): cardinal;
external 'Revert@{app}\Revert.dll cdecl delayload uninstallonly';

procedure RevertAll();
var
    param: String;
    dataDirectory: String;
    temp: String;
    i: Integer;
begin
    dataDirectory := ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\MyAppData');
    StringChangeEx(dataDirectory, '\', '\\', True);
    param := '{"dataDirectory": "' + dataDirectory + '", "registryPath" : "SOFTWARE\\MyReg\\Key"}';

    Revert(param);

    temp := ExpandConstant('{app}\Revert.dll');
    for i := 0 to 10 do
    begin
        UnloadDLL(temp);
        Sleep(500);

        if DeleteFile(temp) then
            break;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
    if (CurUninstallStep = usUninstall) then
    begin
        RevertAll();
    end 
end;
```

Comment: See [Unload a .NET DLL from an unmanaged process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388095/850848).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the real problem, but unload the DLL manually with Windows API works:

```pascal
function GetModuleHandle(moduleName: String): LongWord;
external 'GetModuleHandleW@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function FreeLibrary(module: LongWord): Integer;
external 'FreeLibrary@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  lib: LongWord; 
  res: integer;

repeat
  lib := GetModuleHandle('Revert.dll');
  res := FreeLibrary(lib);
until res = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a modest contribution given how many hairs I have lost myself trying to remove a DLL upon software removal.
I tried a few things and ended up doing the following:

```pascal
case CurUninstallStep of
      usUninstall:
        begin
          Exec('powershell.exe', ExpandConstant('-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Start-Job -FilePath {%TEMP}\mySoft\CleanUtils.ps1 -ArgumentList {%TEMP}\mySoft\'), '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
          Exec('powershell.exe', ExpandConstant('-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Job -ScriptBlock {{ Remove-Item -Recurse -Force {%TEMP}\mySoft"'), '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
        end;
    end;
```

A few things to notice:

- The `UnloadDLL` didn't work for me either, despite trying everything I could. The DLL would simply not get removed by InnoSetup
- The first `Exec` invokes a PowerShell shell. Notice the `-NoExit`. Without that, the job would simply exit without running.
- The `StartJob` creates a detached background process that runs after the uninstaller quits.
- The first instruction executes the following PowerShell script:

```bsh
# Input directory
$temp_dir=$args[0]

Get-ChildItem "$temp_dir" -Force -Filter "*.dll" |
  Foreach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName

    while (Test-Path($file) )
    {
      try
      {
          remove-item -Recurse -Force $file
      }
      catch
      {
          Start-Sleep -seconds 5
      }
    }
  }
```

That script iterates over the list of DLLs and removes all the DLLs in the folder.
The second `Exec` deletes the parent folder. I could have put that instruction into the Powershell script, but I suspect that I would have ended up with the same problem, that is, PowerShell needing that file, thus never ending.
Regarding that second `Exec`, the other difference is that the job is invoked via a `-Command` option. Without that, I would encounter the following error:

```
Start-Job : Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "-encodedCommand" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:1 char:11
+ Start-Job -ScriptBlock -encodedCommand IABHAGUAdAAtAFAAcgBvAGMAZQBzAH ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Job], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand
```

This is far from perfect, but this is the best I could come up with after almost one week(!) of trying bunch of different things.

Good luck to all the Inno fellows!

Comment: See [Unload a .NET DLL from an unmanaged process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388095/850848) for a similar solution.