# How to delete iu-....tmp folder which is created during Inno Setup uninstallation?

Tags: inno-setup

During uninstall process Inno Setup uninstaller will create a folder named `iu-....tmp` in `AppData\Local\Temp` path. According to [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#uninsttemp) it should be deleted while restarting the laptop, but I have noticed that it is not deleted.

I have tried to delete the folder in event function `DeinitializeUninstall()` using `DelTree()` also.

Thanks in advance for those who are helping me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, Inno Setup schedules the temporary folder to be deleted using [WinAPI function `MoveFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw) and its `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag. And that works only if you run the installer as Administrator. Are you? If not, the folder indeed stays. I do not think it's a problem, as Windows will cleanup old folders from the temp folder on its own eventually.

---

Calling `DelTree` from the uninstaller code cannot work. If it were that easy, the uninstaller would do it. The FAQ you refer to yourself explains why:

> The reason the file remains in the directory after the uninstall process has completed is that Windows does not allow running executables to delete themselves.

---

If you really want to solve it, what you can do is to run a new process that will try to delete the folder on the background, once the uninstaller exits. Simple `cmd` process with delayed (and possibly retrying) `del` command would do. For such solution see a similar question:
[Unload a .NET DLL from an unmanaged process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388095/850848#41531880)